# establish communication between 2 test containers [ spring boot and mock server ]

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am running a spring-boot image using GenericContainer option. I want the spring boot container to consume data returned by mockServer. I have created the following class to test the communication:

```
@Slf4j
public class TestContainer {


    private static final Network network = Network.newNetwork();

    private static final WireMockContainer wiremockServer = new WireMockContainer("wiremock/wiremock:2.35.0")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases("mockServer")
            .withMappingFromResource("weatherMock", "MockData/weatherMock.json")
            .withMappingFromResource("locationMock", "MockData/locationMock.json");

    private static final GenericContainer springBootContainer = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("data-retriever"))
            .withNetwork(network);


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("defaultRestTemplate")
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUpMockServers() {
        wiremockServer.start();

        springBootContainer.dependsOn(wiremockServer)
                .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.defaultPolicy())
                .withExposedPorts(20100)
                /* update the spring properties using environment variables and make the spring talk to mock server*/
                .withEnv("weather_data_host", wiremockServer.getBaseUrl()) 
                .withEnv("location_data_host", wiremockServer.getBaseUrl())
                .withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));

        springBootContainer.start();

    }

    @After("@testContainer")
    public void stopContainer() {
        wiremockServer.stop();
        springBootContainer.stop();
    }

    @Given("I am mock dependency using wiremock testcontainers")
    public void iAmMockDependencyUsingWiremockTestcontainers() {

        log.info("dataIngestion server host: {}", springBootContainer.getHost());
        log.info("dataIngestion server port: {}", springBootContainer.getFirstMappedPort());
        String url = String.format("https://%s:%s/retrieveData", springBootContainer.getHost(), springBootContainer.getFirstMappedPort());
        var response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object.class);
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
       
    }
}
```

- When I run the test, I am not receiving a success response because the data-retriever container is not able to communicate to mock server container !!
- I ran the test in debug mode and added a debug point at starting of test where we have the log statement  `log.info("dataIngestion server host: {}", springBootContainer.getHost());` and tried to hit the mock server from the postman and I got a success response along with mocked data.
- I used  `wiremockServer.getBaseUrl()` to get the host and port of mock server

**Question:**

- why the data-retriever container is not able to communicate with the mock-server container even when they both are on same network ?
- Do I need to make any additional config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When containers are connected through the container network. Those should use the network alias to communicate each other. In your case, `weather_data_host` and `location_data_host` should point to `http://mockServer:8080` instead of

```java
.withEnv("weather_data_host", wiremockServer.getBaseUrl()) 
.withEnv("location_data_host", wiremockServer.getBaseUrl())
```

When to use `wiremockServer.getBaseUrl()`?

When you are connecting from outside of the docker network. For example, the java process in your host using the restTemplate

Docs: https://java.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#advanced-networking